# Laravel mix can not share variables between scss and js files

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I'm using laravel mix to build and complie my front-end files, and trying to share variables between scss file and js, here is my scss file and app.js file.

`variables.scss`

```
$color: '#ffffff';


:export{
    color: $color
}
```

`app.js`

```
import variables from './variables.scss'

console.log(variables)
```

It should print an object `{color: '#ffffff'}` defined in `variables.scss` file. But instead It prints out an empty object.

It's a brand new project,

I use `laravel new my-project` to download laravel.

`npm install`, `npm install sass sass-loader --save-dev` to install packages,that's it.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.43.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.2.0"
    }
}
```

so,what's the problem?

Comment: I'd love to know how to get this to work too. the module.exports doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your webpack.config.js?

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: laravel mix has it's own pre-settings. I dont know if is match what you paste.

Comment: And I still dont quit understand why this `/\.css$/` rule gonna work,because I'm importing a scss file, it's not a css file,how does it work?